# How to properly model a non-holonomic system?

Tags: mobile-robot, dynamics

I'm trying to model a robot which is composed of a non-holonomic and a holonomic system overall is non-holonomic. Basically it's a robot arm + mobile platform. So far I have found a similar work like this https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=293207 before the Simulation section, they say they ignore the dynamics of the manipulator over the mobile platform, so they are treated independently. I cannot ignore it. So far I got this:

$$ 
Vel_{mobilePlataform} = \begin{bmatrix} \dot x_1 \\ \dot y_1 \\ \dot z_1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f_x(yaw, pitch, roll) \\ f_y(yaw, pitch, roll) \\ f_z (yaw)\end{bmatrix}  
$$
thanks to this: A tratise on Analytical Dyanmics - L.A.Pars example, the rolling penny.

So the **fx** and **fy** are non integrables, so they are constraints, so far so good. But attaching a single joint on the penny's radios direction. I will get this velocities on the joints
$$
Vel_{joint} = \begin{bmatrix} \dot x_2 \\ \dot y_2 \\ \dot z_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}g_x \\ g_y \\ g_z \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \dot x_1 \\ \dot y_1 \\ \dot z_1 \end {bmatrix}
$$

since **gz** is not integrable, z2 also becomes a constraint. So, the whole system is non-holonomic, right? I'm stuck here.
Then, the equation of motion should be for every Q like this?
$$
Q_{x1}, Q_{y1}, Q_{yaw}, Q_{pitch}, Q_{roll}, Q_{x2}, Q_{y2}, Q_{z2}, Q_{joint-angle}
$$
So, then for computing the lagrange multipliers will be like this

$$
Q_{x1}\delta x_1 + Q_{y1}\delta y_1+ Q_{yaw}\delta(yaw)+ Q_{pitch}\delta(pitch)+ Q_{roll}\delta(roll)+ Q_{x2}\delta x_2+ Q_{y2}\delta y_2+ Q_{z2} \delta z_2+ Q_{joint-angle}\delta(joint-angle) = \lambda_1 (\delta x_1 - f_x) + \lambda_2(\delta y_2 - f_y)+\lambda_3(\delta x_2-g_x-f_x) +\lambda_4(\delta y_2 -g_y-f_y) + \lambda_5(\delta z_2-g_z-f_z)
$$

by grouping terms I can have the values of all `lambdas`, for example:

$$
Q_{x1} = \lambda_1 \\
... \\
Q_{x2} = \lambda_3 
$$

Am I doing ok? Does this mean the trajectory of the linked masses can be independent of each other?